# Minecraft, Dead By Daylight minigame question

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I have a question about a game I am creating. In the game people have to make 5 devices activate and how I plan to do this is they have to click a button 100 times with the command, `/scoreboard players add 1`. My question is how can I sense when 5 different devices are done and have it affect the game by giving strength and destroying/adding buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my interpretation of the game:

There are 5 devices on a map, each will light up as soon as an attached button is clicked 100 times. If all 5 devices are lit, the gate opens and the survivors rush through.

Your `/scoreboard players add 1` is not going to work because there is a lack of parameters.

Your question boils down to how the device is constructed, perhaps in the perfect world it is an iron block with a stone button on top. However, scoreboard variables in minecraft are only available to entities, not blocks.
Therefore you will have to add a marker entity near the machine, or simply summon one inside the machine with exact coordinates. While the button is pressed, a command with `execute as @e[sort=nearest,limit=1,type=marker] run scoreboard players add @s device_var 1` would be run. Then, a chained command block would call the command `execute as @e[sort=nearest,limit=1,type=marker,scores={device_var=100..}] at @s run setblock ~ ~2 ~ minecraft:light` This should check if the device is pressed over 100 or more times.

Detect if light blocks are present at certain coordinates with the `if block` statement in the `execute` command.

```
execute if block x y z light if block x y z light ...... if block x y z light run say openDoor
```

Each tuple of coordinates represent the *exact position* of a potential light source block.

replace the `run say openDoor` with your desired action when all machines have been decoded.

To say in advance, there are many aspects of commands involved in the above and it may take a long time of testing and polishing to really get it to work. The method mentioned above is merely a template and my own intepretation of your design and is by no mean set in stone.

I hope this helps and do you need further elaborations?

Comment: thanks so much!! i have 1 finnall question then the bounty is yours!!!! how would i give stregth to the killer when the deivces are ative

Comment: The killer should have an entity tag that indicates his role. For example, before the game starts, you should tag the killer with ```/tag PlayerName add Killer```. To give strength to the killer after all machines have been decoded, execute the command that detects machine status again. Put this in a repeating command block ```execute if block x y z light.... if block x y z light run effect give @a[tag=Killer] strength 99999 2 false```
That should do the job